# How to measure program execution time in ARM Cortex-A53 processor?

Tags: c, arm64

I was using following method to read clock in cortex-a15:

```
static void readticks(unsigned int *result)
{
    struct timeval t;
    unsigned int cc;
    if (!enabled) {
        // program the performance-counter control-register:
        asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0" :: "r"(17));
        //enable all counters
        asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 1" :: "r"(0x8000000f));
        //Clear overflow.
        asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 3" :: "r"(0x8000000f));
        enabled = 1;
    }
    asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(cc));
    gettimeofday(&t,(struct timezone *) 0);
    result[0] = cc;
    result[1] = t.tv_usec;
    result[2] = t.tv_sec;
}
```

And final performance profilinglooks like:

```
before = readticks();
  foo();
after = readticks();
clock_cycles = after - before.
```

I want to use same logic in cortex-A53, ARM64 (not aarch32).

I have tried this after following online portals:

```
    /* All counters, including PMCCNTR_EL0, are disabled/enabled */

        #define QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_E      (1 << 0)
        /* Reset all event counters, not including PMCCNTR_EL0, to 0

 */
    #define QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_P      (1 << 1)
    /* Reset PMCCNTR_EL0 to 0 */
    #define QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_C      (1 << 2)
    /* Clock divider: PMCCNTR_EL0 counts every clock cycle/every 64 clock cycles */
    #define QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_D      (1 << 3)
    /* Export of events is disabled/enabled */
    #define QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_X      (1 << 4)
    /* Disable cycle counter, PMCCNTR_EL0 when event counting is prohibited */
    #define QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_DP     (1 << 5)
    /* Long cycle count enable */
    #define QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_LC     (1 << 6)

static inline unsigned int armv8_pmu_pmcr_read(void)
{

        unsigned int val;
        /* Read Performance Monitors Control Register */
        asm volatile("mrs %0, pmcr_el0" : "=r" (val));
        return val;
}
static inline void armv8_pmu_pmcr_write(unsigned int val)
{
    asm volatile("msr pmcr_el0, %0" : :"r" (val & QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_WR_MASK));
}

static void enable_all_counters(void)
{
    unsigned int val;
    /* Enable all counters */
    val = armv8_pmu_pmcr_read();
    val |= QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_E | QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_X;
    armv8_pmu_pmcr_write(val);
}

static void reset_all_counters(void)
{

    unsigned int val;
    val = armv8_pmu_pmcr_read();
    val |= QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_P | QUADD_ARMV8_PMCR_C;
    armv8_pmu_pmcr_write(val);
}

static void readticks(unsigned int *result)
{
    struct timeval t;
    unsigned int cc;
    unsigned int val;
    if (!enabled) {
        reset_all_counters();
        enable_all_counters();
        enabled = 1;
    }
    cc = armv8_pmu_pmcr_read();
    gettimeofday(&t,(struct timezone *) 0);
    result[0] = cc;
    result[1] = t.tv_usec;
    result[2] = t.tv_sec;
}
```

But it gives "Illegal instruction" as error while I am trying profiling. Can anyone help me to change the above code for cortex-a53?

Comment: You'd have to first enable userspace access to the PMUs from kernel code for this to work. Be aware, though, that a raw cycle counter is generally a poor tool for profiling; sure there are usually ways to avoid your process getting rescheduled on another CPU and seeing the count suddenly jump backwards or forwards, but what about all those cycles while your code is paused and the CPU is servicing interrupts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the PMU for user mode. Here is the kernel module I wrote for it(For ARM V7 in Raspberry Pi 2):

```
/* Module source file 'module.c'. */
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

arm_write(unsigned long val)
{
        //Enabling both read and write - note difference between mcr and mrc
        asm volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" :: "r"(1));
        asm volatile("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c14, 0" :: "r"(1));

}

static int enabler(void)
{
     unsigned long value = 1;
     printk(KERN_INFO "Enabling PMU usermode.\n");
     arm_write(value);
     return 0;
}

static void end(void)
{
     printk(KERN_INFO "module unloaded.\n");
}

module_init(enabler);
module_exit(end);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Sama");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Blahblah");
```

This will enable user mode access to the PMU. once you compiled it , you need to enable the PMU counters as follow:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int enable_divider =1;
    int do_reset=1;
        int value = 1;

        // peform reset:
        if (do_reset) {
                value |= 2;     // reset all counters to zero.
                value |= 4;     // reset cycle counter to zero.
        }

        if (enable_divider)
                value |= 8;     // enable "by 64" divider for CCNT. You really do not want to get all cycle count. This will increment the counter by 1 for every 64 cpu cycle.

        value |= 16;
        // program the performance-counter control-register with mask constructed above
        asm volatile ("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 0\t\n" :: "r"(value));
        // enable all counters:
        asm volatile ("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 1\t\n" :: "r"(0x8000000f));

        // clear overflows:
        asm volatile ("MCR p15, 0, %0, c9, c12, 3\t\n" :: "r"(0x80000001));

        // Select individual counter (0)
        asm volatile ("MCR p15,   0,    %0,  c9  ,   c12 ,   5\t\n":: "r"(0x00));

        // Write event (0x11 = Cycle count)
        asm volatile ("MCR p15,   0,    %0,  c9  ,   c13 ,   1\t\n":: "r"(0xD));

    printf("Hi");
        unsigned int output;

        // Read current event counter
        asm volatile ("MRC p15,   0,    %0,  c9  ,   c13 ,   2\t\n": "=r"(output));
        printf("Event count 0: %ul\n", output);
    printf("Normal Execution, No Buffer Overflow Occurred.\n");
   return 0;
}
```

However unfortunately what you get is not only your program cpu cycle, but entire system cpu cycle!. So what I recommend is to use perf.

Write your asm code in an inline assembly code in C and then put it like this:

```
int dummya(int z, int b){
//This is my function you need to change it for yourself
struct perf_event_attr pe;
long long count;
int fd;
        memset(&pe, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
        pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
        pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
        pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES;
        pe.disabled = 1;
        pe.exclude_kernel = 1;
        pe.exclude_hv = 1;
        fd = perf_event_open(&pe, 0, -1, -1, 0);
        if (fd == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error opening leader %llx\n", pe.config);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
               }

        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, 0);
        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, 0);
//From here the counter starts.
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
        asm("Your ASM Codes");
//Disabling Counter
        ioctl(fd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, 0);

        read(fd, &count, sizeof(long long));
        printf("%lld\n", count);
        close(fd);
return 5;
}
```

And be advised you need a new kernels to access the Perf driver.

Comment: In the first part of the answer you show the module enabling access to PMU. How do I 'install' this module?